# What "inconsistent synchronization" means?

Tags: java, synchronization

This is my Java 1.6 class:

```
public class Foo {
  private ArrayList<String> names;
  public void scan() {
    if (names == null) {
      synchronized (this) {
        this.names = new ArrayList<String>();
        // fill the array with data
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Findbugs says:

```
Inconsistent synchronization of com.XXX.Foo.names; locked 40% of time
```

What does it mean and what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to avoid problems when two or more clients call `Foo.scan()` at the same time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's beacuse you are only synchronizing when you set the `names` variable and not when you read it. So between the read and the write another thread could execute and you'd create two ArrayLists and fill them with data, the first one created would get GC'ed.

You need to put the synchronized block around the read and the write or add the synchronized modifier to the method.

```
public class Foo {
  private ArrayList<String> names;
    public void scan() {
      synchronized (this)
        if (names == null) {
           this.names = new ArrayList<String>();
           // fill the array with data
         }
       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: If you plan on using this idiom, the names variable should be marked volatile.

Comment: You should also check to see if `names` is null before you enter the sychrnoize block. This avoids locking when it's not necessary.

Comment: @Phil M why should names be marked volatile? I thought that synchonized provides the same visibility as volatile. So you wouldnt be adding anything so long as all access to names uses the same lock.

Comment: If you're using the synchronized keyword, then you're expecting instances of class Foo to be shared between multiple threads. Reassignment of the names field in one thread will not necessarily be visible immediately (or at all) to other threads unless the field is marked volatile. See http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile_typical_use.shtml for detail.

Comment: If you are only accessing the variable from within the synchronized block, the variable does *not* need to be volatile. You should use volatile if you are accessing it from outside the synchronized block, and even then, it won't prevent (in this case, say) reading a null, while another thread is already in the synchronized block.

Comment: @brain How can you say with absolute certainty that the first one created will be garbage collected? It could be the second one as well ?

Comment: @Geek, "locked 40%" means that some access to the variable names is in synchronized blocks and some isn't. Also, only the last ArrayList created will end up being referenced so the first will be garbage.

Answer (score 8):

The first time you reference `names` inside `scan` is outside of `synchronized` block.
E.g., if `scan` is called twice from two different threads and `names` is null, it may go like this

1. `if (names == null)` from the first thread is processed (to `true`).
2. `if (names == null)` from the second thread is processed (to `true`).
3. First thread enters `synchronized` block, assignes `names` and leaves `synchronized` block.
4. Second thread enters `synchronized` block, assignes `names` and leaves `synchronized` block.

Now, `names` is initialized twice. And this is only one possible scenario where you get unexpected results.

Comment: `locked 40% of time` what does it stands for in warning