# Inconsistent synchronization during singleton initialization

Tags: java, asynchronous, synchronization

I have a singleton `PayloadFetcher` that uses a `consumer` to fetch payload.
I have the `initConsumer` function `synchronized` so that `consumer` singleton is visible across multiple threads.
Howver SpotBugs complains about "Inconsistent synchronization" unless I add `synchronized` to `doFetch` function too, which doesn't seem necessary to me.
Could anyone help with my understanding?

```java
public class PayloadFetcher {

  private Consumer consumer;

  public Payload fetch() {
    final Payload payload = doFetch();
    // ...
    return payload;
  }

  // SpotBugs want this to be synchronized too
  private Payload doFetch() {
    final Consumer consumer = initConsumer();
    // ...
  }

  private synchronized Consumer initConsumer() {
    if (consumer == null) {
      // init consumer
    } else {
      return consumer;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you give an example how this class is initialized and used?

Comment: It is used as a singleton managed by Spring and to be used like `payloadFetcher.fetch()`

Comment: Shouldn't your private Consumer consumer; be static (so you've the same instance accross all the classes)?

Comment: `PayloadFetcher` will be set up as a singleton so I don't think it matters @Joan

Comment: SpotBugs uses "static analysis" to look for bugs in Java. Maybe it doesn't understand what Spring is actually doing, and how it manages the scope of the beans.

Comment: Can you post a complete, minimal example (including a pom which runs SpotBugs) which reproduces this?

Comment: Most likely, SpotBugs infers from the fact that `initConsumer()` is `synchronized` that it is expected to be executed by multiple threads, which implies that `doFetch()` may be executed by multiple threads and hence, must be thread safe. Is `doFetch()` thread safe? We don’t know. Everything but the first line has been omitted. SpotBugs complains about the entire method, you ask us about its first line only…

Comment: What's the *complete* message from spotbugs? Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187286/what-inconsistent-synchronization-means) I'd expect it to be giving you some more detail...